# Post build event firing before exe creation in WIX project (VS2012)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wix, post-build-event

We are moving to VS2012 from VS2010 due to which we have to opt for WIX for creating setups.

I am facing an issue in VS2012. I have created a wix setup and output gives me a msi and an exe.

I want to rename this exe with in post build event but the post build rename command fails because .exe is creating after execution of post build events.

Issue is in wix project only.

Comment: Somebody please help in this issue. I am in need of solution.

Comment: You might consider using a WiX Bootstrapper project to build the EXE. Otherwise, please show how you are doing it and the post build event.

Comment: Thanks for reply @TomBlodget.I have created a WiX setup project i.e. giving me a msi and an exe. On post build event of project, I am simply renaming the exe :

rename "$(ProjectDir)$(Configuration)\setup.exe" "Newsetup.exe"

Now, the concern I am facing is setu.exe is generating after execution of post build events.